# $paged always 0

Tags: pagination

I have problem with pagination. For archive page, pagination works perfectly.

Example url: https://www.example.com/tum-urunler/page/2/ (tum-urunler is archive slug for custom post type "urun")

But if i add taxonomy parameters pagination not working.

Example url:https://www.example.com/tur/bebek/page/2/
(tur is taxonomy and bebek is term)

It redirects me 404.php. So i dumped wp_query in 404.php and i saw paged is 0.
Here is my dumped wp_query when pagination not working

```
object(WP_Query)#73 (50) { ["query"]=> array(2) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "urun" ["tur"]=> string(1) "2" } ["query_vars"]=> array(67) { ["post_type"]=> string(4) "urun" ["tur"]=> string(1) "2" ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["m"]=> string(0) "" ["p"]=> int(0) ["post_parent"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost"]=> string(0) "" ["subpost_id"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment"]=> string(0) "" ["attachment_id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(0) "" ["static"]=> string(0) "" ["pagename"]=> string(0) "" ["page_id"]=> int(0) ["second"]=> string(0) "" ["minute"]=> string(0) "" ["hour"]=> string(0) "" ["day"]=> int(0) ["monthnum"]=> int(0) ["year"]=> int(0) ["w"]=> int(0) ["category_name"]=> string(0) "" ["tag"]=> string(0) "" ["cat"]=> string(0) "" ["tag_id"]=> string(0) "" ["author"]=> string(0) "" ["author_name"]=> string(0) "" ["feed"]=> string(0) "" ["tb"]=> string(0) "" ["paged"]=> int(0) ["meta_key"]=> string(0) "" ["meta_value"]=> string(0) "" ["preview"]=> string(0) "" ["s"]=> string(0) "" ["sentence"]=> string(0) "" ["title"]=> string(0) "" ["fields"]=> string(0) "" ["menu_order"]=> string(0) "" ["embed"]=> string(0) "" ["category__in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["category__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_name__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag__and"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__in"]=> array(0) { } ["tag_slug__and"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__in"]=> array(0) { } ["post_parent__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__in"]=> array(0) { } ["author__not_in"]=> array(0) { } ["ignore_sticky_posts"]=> bool(false) ["suppress_filters"]=> bool(false) ["cache_results"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_term_cache"]=> bool(true) ["lazy_load_term_meta"]=> bool(true) ["update_post_meta_cache"]=> bool(true) ["posts_per_page"]=> int(10) ["nopaging"]=> bool(false) ["comments_per_page"]=> string(2) "50" ["no_found_rows"]=> bool(false) ["taxonomy"]=> string(3) "tur" ["term"]=> string(1) "2" ["order"]=> string(4) "DESC" } ["tax_query"]=> object(WP_Tax_Query)#2946 (6) { ["queries"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(5) { ["taxonomy"]=> string(3) "tur" ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" ["operator"]=> string(2) "IN" ["include_children"]=> bool(true) } } ["relation"]=> string(3) "AND" ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["queried_terms"]=> array(1) { ["tur"]=> array(2) { ["terms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "2" } ["field"]=> string(4) "slug" } } ["primary_table"]=> string(8) "tr_posts" ["primary_id_column"]=> string(2) "ID" } ["meta_query"]=> object(WP_Meta_Query)#2947 (9) { ["queries"]=> array(0) { } ["relation"]=> NULL ["meta_table"]=> NULL ["meta_id_column"]=> NULL ["primary_table"]=> NULL ["primary_id_column"]=> NULL ["table_aliases":protected]=> array(0) { } ["clauses":protected]=> array(0) { } ["has_or_relation":protected]=> bool(false) } ["date_query"]=> bool(false) ["queried_object"]=> NULL ["queried_object_id"]=> NULL ["request"]=> string(296) "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS tr_posts.ID FROM tr_posts WHERE 1=1 AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND tr_posts.post_type = 'urun' AND (tr_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR tr_posts.post_status = 'acf-disabled' OR tr_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY tr_posts.ID ORDER BY tr_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10" ["posts"]=> &array(0) { } ["post_count"]=> int(0) ["current_post"]=> int(-1) ["in_the_loop"]=> bool(false) ["comment_count"]=> int(0) ["current_comment"]=> int(-1) ["found_posts"]=> int(0) ["max_num_pages"]=> int(0) ["max_num_comment_pages"]=> int(0) ["is_single"]=> bool(false) ["is_preview"]=> bool(false) ["is_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_archive"]=> bool(false) ["is_date"]=> bool(false) ["is_year"]=> bool(false) ["is_month"]=> bool(false) ["is_day"]=> bool(false) ["is_time"]=> bool(false) ["is_author"]=> bool(false) ["is_category"]=> bool(false) ["is_tag"]=> bool(false) ["is_tax"]=> bool(false) ["is_search"]=> bool(false) ["is_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_comment_feed"]=> bool(false) ["is_trackback"]=> bool(false) ["is_home"]=> bool(false) ["is_404"]=> bool(true) ["is_embed"]=> bool(false) ["is_paged"]=> bool(false) ["is_admin"]=> bool(false) ["is_attachment"]=> bool(false) ["is_singular"]=> bool(false) ["is_robots"]=> bool(false) ["is_posts_page"]=> bool(false) ["is_post_type_archive"]=> bool(false) ["query_vars_hash":"WP_Query":private]=> string(32) "51d66ab84e27563088d67225fda32f66" ["query_vars_changed":"WP_Query":private]=> bool(false) ["thumbnails_cached"]=> bool(false) ["stopwords":"WP_Query":private]=> NULL ["compat_fields":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(15) "query_vars_hash" [1]=> string(18) "query_vars_changed" } ["compat_methods":"WP_Query":private]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "init_query_flags" [1]=> string(15) "parse_tax_query" } }
```

I don't know why page parameter un url not handled by wordpress. I need help. Thanks so much

Comment: Have you visited your permalinks page in the admin?

Comment: yes my permalinks are set to /%post_id%-%postname%/ but this should only effect single posts not taxonomy files. Am i right?

Comment: It's look like `tur` is the paged value, does it work if you remove the taxonomy from the url and leave only the term ?

Comment: No it is not working

Comment: You have a rewrite rules conflict, please post both post type and taxonomy registration code. If you look at the query, you can see that WP is trying to query for the term with slug `2` in your taxonomy, which is obviously not correct.

Comment: @SüleymanKenar can you post your solution as an answer and select it as the correct solution please?

Comment: I can't accept before 2 days :\

Answer (score 0):

```
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array( 

        '(tur|tip|tedarikci|beden|mevsim)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=urun&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)

    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );
```

I had this rewrite rule in my functions php. This was overwriting page variable. So i added one more rewrite rule to handle page variable. Here is last version of function

```
function eg_add_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $new_rules = array( 
        '(tur|tip|tedarikci|beden|mevsim)/(.+)/(page|paged)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=urun&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2) .'&paged=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(4),

        '(tur|tip|tedarikci|beden|mevsim)/(.+)/?$' => 'index.php?post_type=urun&' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(1) . '=' . $wp_rewrite->preg_index(2)

    );
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $new_rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'eg_add_rewrite_rules' );
```